# C# desktop aplication throws a Cryptographic Exception in the run time

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

First of all, let me admit that I am very new to C#, specially on using Cryptography. 
I developed a C# application to manage my log on and password information. I read the info from a Winform and store in an XML. the XML is encrypted.

The program works just fine in the machine where I have the code. Works in debugger and also works when I use the exe (out side of visual studio).

Now when I take the exe (whole bin directory) to my home computer (has C# express 2010), it crashes while trying to read/write any information in the xml. This is the error I get in exception dialog:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle hPubKey, Byte[] key, Int32 dwFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter.DecryptKeyExchange(Byte[] rgbIn)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.DecryptKey(Byte[] keyData, RSA rsa, Boolean useOAEP)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.GetDecryptionKey(EncryptedData encryptedData, String symmetricAlgorithmUri)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.DecryptDocument()
   at MyCal.Calendar.Decrypt(String Doc, RSA Alg, String KeyName) in C:\Users\mpaudel\Desktop\MyCal\MyCal\Form1.cs:line 191
   at MyCal.Calendar.btnSaveAdd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\mpaudel\Desktop\MyCal\MyCal\Form1.cs:line 971
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5448 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
MyCal
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/remoteuser/Desktop/Release/MyCal.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5446 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5453 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.Calendar
    Assembly Version: 1.0.4359.17528
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/remoteuser/Desktop/Release/System.Windows.Forms.Calendar.DLL
----------------------------------------
RicherTextBox
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/remoteuser/Desktop/Release/RicherTextBox.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
33fead0k
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5453 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.mshtml
    Assembly Version: 7.0.3300.0
    Win32 Version: 7.0.3300.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC/Microsoft.mshtml/7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.mshtml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Security
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Security/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Please help me get through this.
Thanks a lot for looking into it.
- MP

**Update:-**

Here is my code. Please excuse if the code is horrible :-) It is my learning project.

```
public partial class frmLogOn : Form
    {
        public frmLogOn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string LOGON_FILE_NAME = "logon.xml";//"logon.xml";

        private void btnEnterLogon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_ENC_RSA_KEY";
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams); 
            Decrypt(LOGON_FILE_NAME, rsaKey, "rsaKey");


            //Read Password from the xml file
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            if (File.Exists(LOGON_FILE_NAME))
            {
                XmlTextReader rdrXml = new XmlTextReader(LOGON_FILE_NAME);
                string existingpswd;
                do
                {
                       switch (rdrXml.NodeType)
                       {
                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        existingpswd = rdrXml.Value;
                        if (this.txtpswdLogon.Text == existingpswd)
                        {
                            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Password did not match", "Validate Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                            rdrXml.Close();
                            Encrypt(LOGON_FILE_NAME, "Pswrds", "EncryptedElement1", rsaKey, "rsaKey");
                            return;

                        }
                        break;
                       }


                } while (rdrXml.Read());
                rdrXml.Close();
                Encrypt(LOGON_FILE_NAME, "Pswrds", "EncryptedElement1", rsaKey, "rsaKey");
            }
        }

        private void chkChangepswdLogon_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.chkChangepswdLogon.Checked == true)
            {
                this.Height = 180;
                this.txtNewPswdLogon.Visible = true;
                this.txtOldPswdLogon.Visible = true;
                this.btnChangeLogOn.Visible = true;
                this.txtOldPswdLogon.Focus();
            }
            else if (this.chkChangepswdLogon.Checked == false)
            {
                this.Height = 105;
                this.txtNewPswdLogon.Visible = false;
                this.txtOldPswdLogon.Visible = false;
                this.btnChangeLogOn.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void frmLogOn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnChangeLogOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_ENC_RSA_KEY";
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);


            Decrypt(LOGON_FILE_NAME, rsaKey, "rsaKey");
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(LOGON_FILE_NAME);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
            XmlNode oldRecord;
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            try
            {
                oldRecord = root.SelectSingleNode("/Pswrds/pswd[password='" + this.txtOldPswdLogon.Text + "']");
                if (oldRecord == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong existing password, not authorized to change");
                    this.txtNewPswdLogon.Text = "";
                    this.txtOldPswdLogon.Text = "";
                    this.txtpswdLogon.Text = "";
                    return;
                    Encrypt(LOGON_FILE_NAME, "Pswrds", "EncryptedElement1", rsaKey, "rsaKey");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong existing password, not authorized to change");
                return;
                Encrypt(LOGON_FILE_NAME, "Pswrds", "EncryptedElement1", rsaKey, "rsaKey");
            }
            string aa = oldRecord.Value;
            XmlElement newRecord = doc.CreateElement("pswd");

            newRecord.InnerXml = "<password>" + this.txtNewPswdLogon.Text + "</password>" ;

            root.ReplaceChild(newRecord, oldRecord);
            //save the output to a file 
            doc.Save(LOGON_FILE_NAME);
            MessageBox.Show("Password successfully changed.");
            this.txtNewPswdLogon.Text = "";
            this.txtOldPswdLogon.Text = "";
            this.txtpswdLogon.Text = "";
            this.chkChangepswdLogon.Checked = false;


            Encrypt(LOGON_FILE_NAME, "Pswrds", "EncryptedElement1", rsaKey, "rsaKey");
        }



        public static void Encrypt(string Doc, string ElementToEncrypt, string EncryptionElementID, RSA Alg, string KeyName)
        {
            // Create an XmlDocument object.
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(Doc);

            // Check the arguments.
            if (Doc == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");
            if (ElementToEncrypt == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ElementToEncrypt");
            if (EncryptionElementID == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("EncryptionElementID");
            if (Alg == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Alg");
            if (KeyName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("KeyName");

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Find the specified element in the XmlDocument
            // object and create a new XmlElemnt object.
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            XmlElement elementToEncrypt = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName(ElementToEncrypt)[0] as XmlElement;

            // Throw an XmlException if the element was not found.
            if (elementToEncrypt == null)
            {
                throw new XmlException("The specified element was not found");

            }
            RijndaelManaged sessionKey = null;

            try
            {
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Create a new instance of the EncryptedXml class
                // and use it to encrypt the XmlElement with the
                // a new random symmetric key.
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // Create a 256 bit Rijndael key.
                sessionKey = new RijndaelManaged();
                sessionKey.KeySize = 256;

                EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();

                byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, sessionKey, false);
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Construct an EncryptedData object and populate
                // it with the desired encryption information.
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////

                EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData();
                edElement.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;
                edElement.Id = EncryptionElementID;
                // Create an EncryptionMethod element so that the
                // receiver knows which algorithm to use for decryption.

                edElement.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url);
                // Encrypt the session key and add it to an EncryptedKey element.
                EncryptedKey ek = new EncryptedKey();

                byte[] encryptedKey = EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(sessionKey.Key, Alg, false);

                ek.CipherData = new CipherData(encryptedKey);

                ek.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url);

                // Create a new DataReference element
                // for the KeyInfo element.  This optional
                // element specifies which EncryptedData
                // uses this key.  An XML document can have
                // multiple EncryptedData elements that use
                // different keys.
                DataReference dRef = new DataReference();

                // Specify the EncryptedData URI.
                dRef.Uri = "#" + EncryptionElementID;

                // Add the DataReference to the EncryptedKey.
                ek.AddReference(dRef);
                // Add the encrypted key to the
                // EncryptedData object.

                edElement.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoEncryptedKey(ek));
                // Set the KeyInfo element to specify the
                // name of the RSA key.


                // Create a new KeyInfoName element.
                KeyInfoName kin = new KeyInfoName();

                // Specify a name for the key.
                kin.Value = KeyName;

                // Add the KeyInfoName element to the
                // EncryptedKey object.
                ek.KeyInfo.AddClause(kin);
                // Add the encrypted element data to the
                // EncryptedData object.
                edElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Replace the element from the original XmlDocument
                // object with the EncryptedData element.
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, false);
                xmlDoc.Save(Doc);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // re-throw the exception.
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sessionKey != null)
                {
                    sessionKey.Clear();
                }

            }

        }

        public static void Decrypt(string Doc, RSA Alg, string KeyName)
        {
            // Create an XmlDocument object.
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(Doc);
            // Check the arguments.  
            if (Doc == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");
            if (Alg == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Alg");
            if (KeyName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("KeyName");

            // Create a new EncryptedXml object.
            EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml(xmlDoc);

            // Add a key-name mapping.
            // This method can only decrypt documents
            // that present the specified key name.
            exml.AddKeyNameMapping(KeyName, Alg);

            // Decrypt the element.
            exml.DecryptDocument();
            xmlDoc.Save(Doc);

        }





    }
```

Comment: Dear Erik, Thanks for quick response. I added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that both the machines I was trying to run the application did not have X.509 certificates installed because of which the code would throw exception while trying to decrypt. I Installed the certificate from this link [microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089], recompiled the application and now it works like a charm!! Thanks everyone for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

These are comments, but the comment box is not large enough to contain them. This code:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    // re-throw the exception.
    throw e;
}
```

is discarding your stack trace so you can't see what causes errors. Remove that code.

I suspect the `Doc` you are passing to `Decrypt` is not valid. Set a breakpoint before you call `xmlDoc.Load(Doc)` and inspect it. You'll have to show us what you are passing for `Doc`, or at least where `MyCal.Calendar.btnSaveAdd_Click` is getting it.

Also, you are calling

```
if (Doc == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");
```

**after** using `Doc` in `xmlDoc.Load(Doc)`. That's too late, you must validate arguments before using them, not after.

Comment: Dear Dour,

Thanks a ton for your response.

I made changes to reflect your corrections in the code.

Weirdest thing is the code is working fine in the machine where I have the code but does not work on any other machine.

About Doc, it is an XML file located in the bin directory. It stores this:

<Pswrds>

  <pswd>

    <password>test</password>

  </pswd>

</Pswrds>

The user is supposed to enter this password to use the application. Once I enter the password, then code is supposed to open this XML file, decrypt it, read the saved password and compare it to what the user enters.

Comment: to continue to my comment to Dour:


I checked and the decryption is working fine in this machine where I can run the debugger.

Comment: Dear Friends,

I opened the solution on another machine and was able to find the point where it breaks:

It fails on the following line of:

`public static void Decrypt(string Doc, RSA Alg, string KeyName)`
`// Decrypt the element`
`exml.DecryptDocument(); `


Again, it is surprising to me that the exact same code does not fail on one machine and the decryption works just fine. Could it be related to any of VS or windows updates?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what "it fails" means. If it throws an exception, add the exception message to your question. Windows updates could be a factor, but we don't know what updates you have installed on the machines that work and the ones that don't. You have to tell us. Are you using an X.509 certificate? That has to be installed on all machines doing the decryption.

Comment: Check the key length of your certificate; I believe the base CryptoServiceProvider only supports RSA keys up to 512 bits. You need the Strong CryptoServiceProvider to support longer lengths. What OSes are you usnig? Are you using a US version of Windows or an International one? I believe the CSPs are different for those as well. Also, are you getting certificates from a file or from a smart card?

Comment: @ Dour,

Sorry about that. Yes by "it fails" I meant it threw an exception. Here is the message:

`An unhandled exception of type ``'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

`Additional information: Bad Data.`

I am sorry to say that I did not know about decryption certificate (such a X.509) until just now. how would I check which version do I have? I have not installed that myself which could potentially be the problem. Which one do you suggest?

OS = Windows 7 enterprise, 64 bit, US version

I see some hope now that my problem will be solved. Thanks !

Comment: Please add the full message, including stack trace, to the question not the comments. I do not know where you are getting decryption keys, an X.509 certificate is only one possibility. You have to find out and tell us. You can install certificates from the Microsoft Management Console or Start > Control Panels > Internet Options > Content > Certificates. You can see what CSPs are installed from the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider registry hive.

Comment: @ Dour, I finally found that both the machines I was trying to run the application did not have X.509 certificates installed. Installed it from this link [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089], recompiled and now it works like a charm!! Thanks for all your help!